# Not breaking line after li and keep the bullet

Tags: html, css

I want to not break line after `li` and keep the bullet. Meaning using the style `display: inline` which removes the bullet is not good for me.

Is there a way to do it?

This is what I have:

```css
li {float: left; clear: left;}
span {float: left;}
```

```html
<ul class="c2">
    <div>
        <span>
           <li>line1</li>
           <li>line2</li>
           <li>line3</li>
           <li>line4</li>
       </span>        
       <span>I want this in same line as line4</span>
    </div>
</ul>
```

the problem is that whenever `li` is used since its `display style` is `list-item`, the line breaks.

Comment: That is invalid HTML so not going to happen. The span has to be in the li.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearest solution is to put `span` into last `li` [(`span` can't be inside `UL` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)).

```html
<ul class="c2">
    <li>line1</li>
    <li>line2</li>
    <li>line3</li>
    <li>line4 <span>I want this in same line as line4</span></li>
</ul>
```

If you need to have `span` as a solo element (I've used your code), than you can use something like that

```css
li {float: left; clear: left;}
span {float: left;}
```

```html
<ul class="c2">
    <li>line1</li>
    <li>line2</li>
    <li>line3</li>
    <li>line4</li>
    <span>I want this in same line as line4</span>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey,
thanks
I tried this, but I guess I need to add to my question somethings, since your answer didnt work. adding some more elements..

Comment: @SagiCohen: click 'Run code snippet' button (the second one), I think it works as expected...

Comment: It did work as expected, but I noticed I had some changes in my html which made it not work, I updated the html. sorry and thanks

Comment: @sagicohen your previous HTML markup was terrible. The new one is worse and I dont think you can achieve that. Please change your HTML markup (span into LI) or at least at the previous version mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use grid for `ul` element.

```css
.c2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px; // optional
}

li {
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c2">
    <li>line1</li>
    <li>line2</li>
    <li>line3</li>
    <li>line4</li>
    <span>I want this in same line as line4</span>
</ul>
```